# What are different types of string/int as in data types that can be input by the person playing a game in python. (I am using pycharm)

Tags: python, user-defined-data-types

How to input an integer data type as a user playing a game? I have tried many things but they don't work. I have tried inputing numbers but they still are strings not integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python3 use:

```
x = int(input(3))
```

and in python2 use:

```
input(3)
```